# How do I disable the Windows Error messages if a program crashes?

Tags: windows, crash

Is there any way how to disable the messages displaying when a program crashes? I am talking about the one asking you to send details to Microsoft or not.

My server sometimes crashes and it probably does not release the sockets until it's not fully terminated, which means the crash message must be gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the error reports [like this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7863/disable-error-reporting-in-xp-vista-and-windows-7/):

### Windows 7

Open Start, and type "problem reporting settings" into the search box. Select "Choose how to report problems". You can also go to *Action Center* → *Change Action Center Settings* → *Problem Reporting Settings*.

In the window opening, select "Never check for solutions".

[image: Windows 7]

---

### Windows Vista

Open your Control Panel, select "Classic View" and open "Problem Reports and Solutions". Look for "Tasks" on the left and click "Change Settings".

In the newly opening window, select "Advanced Settings". Under "For my programs, problem reporting is…", select "Off".

[image: Windows Vista]

---

### Windows XP

Right-click "My Computer" and select "Properties". Click the "Advanced" tab in the newly opened window and select "Error Reporting" at the bottom.

Here, select "Disable error reporting" and click OK.

[image: Windows XP]